# Change Font-Awesome Favourite button on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to implement a favourite button to every element of a list of div elements. On click it should change from a fa-star-o button to a yellow fa-star button. It works to change it on click as intended, but unfortunately only for the very first element and I don't really know why and how to change it.

HTML

```
<input id='fav' type='checkbox'>
          <label for='fav'>
            <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" ></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star fa-3x" ></i>
          </label>
```

CSS

```
 :root {
    font: 400 16px/1.5 Verdana;
  }
  
  #fav {
    display: none; 
  }

  .fa{
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    top: 0.5em;
  }
.fa-star{
  -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow;
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.03em;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}

  #fav+label {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px grey;
    padding: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;
  }
  
  #fav::after {
    color: orange;
  }
  
  #fav+label>.fa-star-o {
    display: inline-block
  }
  
  #fav+label>.fa-star {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #fav:checked+label>.fa-star-o {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #fav:checked+label>.fa-star {
    display: inline-block
  }
```

I really don't know how to improve it, so help would be really much appreciated.

Comment: how about posting your javascript as well

Comment: Without seeing the JS it's hard to give an answer. Double-check that the inputs have unique `id`s though.

Comment: I do not  have a js, unfortunately, and I don't know really how to do it to be honest. It's project I'm trying but I had a lot of trouble with js

Comment: "...only for the very first element..."  Can you clarify this? Your code seems to work fine

Comment: I do have a star in every div element I have on that html, but if I click on any of them, non but the very first on changes

Comment: `.fa {position: absolute; right: 1em; top: 0.5em;}` is the problem/culprit because it's common to all, therefor you have them stacked on top of one another so only the one highest z-axis-wise (z-index) gets affected, if you comment that out... https://jsfiddle.net/e1wu3Ldz/2/ So don't apply styles/rules to the fa class.

Comment: Oh good thank you! But is there another way then to get them in the right position then?

Comment: Np, sure, lots of possibilies, 1 e.g. give each label an unique class/id and apply styles as per desire.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot

Comment: Another way would be to try with position relative instead of absolute, then you can use the fa class.